# How to prevent org-tags-view from creating latex previews?

Tags: org-mode

When running `org-tags-view`, I see a message "Creating Latex previews in buffer..." for 10+ seconds. It appears all files in my org directory are recursively parsed for latex fragments. Is this expected behavior? How would I prevent it?

Comment: Does it happen when you start emacs with `-q` so that it does not load your init file? It does not happen to me at all, so I suspect you have something in your init file causing this. If so, bisect it to find out the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution?

I had a similar problem while using another package (helpful). When I called `helpful-callable`, I got the same message ("Creating Latex previews in buffer...") for a long time.

This is what was happening apparently:

1. I had made org-mode the default major mode for new buffers: my .emacs file had

   ```
   (setq-default major-mode 'org-mode)
   ```
2. When the `helpful-callable` function created a new buffer, org-mode ran a hook to build latex preview images, showing the message and causing the delay.
3. Everything got back to normal when I commented out that line in my .emacs file.

Comment: Was the hook something you added in your init file? Or was it something built-in? If the forrmer, then that makes this answer an extremely unlikely explanation of the OP's problem - you'd need two rather unlikely coincidences: setting the default mode *and* adding a problematic function to some hook. If the latter, you should add what hook it was and what function it was running, so it can be fixed (if indeed it is buggy). I should point out that starting with `emacs -q` would inform you that the bug is not coming from Emacs: it comes from your init file.

Comment: No , i did not add the hook to preview LaTeX fragments when creating org buffers.

What I know so far is:

1. The creation of previews is controlled by the variable `org-startup-with-latex-preview`.

2. The only function that emits the message "Creating Latex previews in buffer..." is `org-latex-preview`. Why this function was being run is a mystery to me.

3. The problem did not happen with `emacs -q`, but then org-mode is not even loaded.

Would be nice if the OP would chime in.

Comment: Before and after I fixed the problem, the only mentions to org hooks in my .emacs file were to `org-autolist-mode`, some yasnippet functions, `turn-on-auto-fill`, `org-num-mode`, `org-superstar-mode`, and `turn-on-org-cdlatex`.

Comment: You can use a minimal init file to duplicate the settings that are absolutely needed, but none of the other things that your init files does. You can use `#+STARTUP: latexpreview` to enable `org-startup-with-latex-preview` on a single file so that you can test. Org mode is packaged with emacs, so opening a file in Org mode would actually load it even with `emacs -q`, although it might be a different version than the one you normally use. But even that would tell you something.

Comment: Does the *Messages* buffer show anything useful?

Comment: @NickD I stripped my .emacs down to the following:
`(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(require 'helpful)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h f") #'helpful-callable)
(setq-default major-mode 'org-mode)`
I start emacs. I do not visit any files. Then, in the *scratch* buffer, I type `C-h f org--get-local-tags` and the problem happens. 
No, the messages buffer doesn't show anything besides the message "Creating Latex previews in buffer...".

Comment: `package-initialize` says: "Load Emacs Lisp packages, and activate them", so every package you have installed in the past is activated. You got to do it without loading all the packages.